# Problema con base de datos SQL y Python

Tags: python, sqlite

Estoy intentando crear una función que añada una tabla, characters, pero al hacerlo por medio del algoritmo, me da error, mientas que si en vez de correr `c.execute(completedString)` pongo dentro directamente: `"""CREATE TABLE characters ( Names text, FirstConstelation text)"""`, funciona bien.

Muchas gracias de antemano.

```py
import sqlite3
    
def table_inside(databasename,Elements):
    conn = sqlite3.connect(databasename) #Creating or connecting to a data base
    c = conn.cursor() #creating a cursor
    basicString = "CREATE TABLE characters ("
    for elmts in Elements:
        if type(elmts) == "<class 'str'>":
            type_elmts = 'text'
        else:
            type_elmts = 'text'
        basicString = basicString + ' {0} {1},'.format(elmts, type_elmts)
    completedString = ('"""'+basicString[:-1]+')"""')
    c.execute(completedString)
    conn.commit()
    conn.close()

dataBaseName = 'genshinCharacters2.sql'
insertElements = ['Names','FirstConstelation']
    
table_inside(dataBaseName,insertElements)
```

```
Error: near """"CREATE TABLE characters ( Names text, FirstConstelation text)"""": syntax error
```

Comment: Intenta enviandolo asi: `f"""CREATE TABLE characters ( {Names}, {Constelation} text)"""`, donde`Names` y `Constelation` son tus variables con su valor

Answer (score 0):

Tu problema está en esta línea:

```
completedString = ('"""'+basicString[:-1]+')"""')
```

Con esto se soluciona:

```
completedString = basicString[:-1] + ')'
```

Sugeriría que no le pusieras a la base de datos la extensión .sql ya que esta se usa para archivos de texto SQL. En su lugar usa **.db** o **.db3** o **.sqlite3**. De todas formas debe funcionar correctamente omitiéndolo.

Por otro lado un nombre de columna siempre es una cadena, por lo que esta comparación SIEMPRE va a ser string: `if type(elmts)`, así que no tiene ningún sentido tenerla. Lo que puedes hacer es mandarle el tipo desde la llamada de la función. Con esta otra función puedes crear más tablas en esa base de datos solo enviándole los parámetros.

```
import sqlite3

def table_inside(databasename, table):
    conn = sqlite3.connect(databasename) #Creating or connecting to a data base
    c = conn.cursor() #creating a cursor
    columns = ', '.join(table['cols'])
    query = "CREATE TABLE {} ({})".format(table['name'], columns)
    c.execute(query)
    conn.commit()
    conn.close()

dataBaseName = 'genshinCharacters2.db3'
table = {'name':'characters', 'cols':['Names VARCHAR(45)', 'FirstConstelation TEXT']}

table_inside(dataBaseName, table)
```

Comment: muchas gracias por tu ayuda y larga explicación, por lo que veo, si se usa .db3, para crear una TABLE a nombre de lo que le llegue después de  ("CREATE TABLE {} <--Aquí), las columnas, estarán dentro del los paréntesis, separadas por comas, para indicar, que tipos hay, TEXT' para textos, VARCHAR(45)' que no sé para que sirve, me podrías pasar webs, donde haya teoría, de python + sqlite3? si no es mucho pedir sjsjajaj <3